# Upgrading from Edubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 using iso

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, system-installation

I have Edubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 running in my computer. I have Edubuntu 14.04 iso and I want to upgrade to edubuntu 14.04 using USB stick. Will upgrade keep all my files and settings ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Edubuntu 13.10, and then proceeded to upgrade to Edubuntu 14.04.

Boot from the USB stick, and install normal.  When I got to the Installation Type screen, I choose Upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to Edubuntu 14.04 LTS.

It will say Upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to Edubuntu 14.04LTS.  Once done, I had Edubuntu 14.04 installed.

[image]

Comment: That option is not available for me. Will upgrade from Ubuntu not Edubuntu?

Comment: What options are available?  The image is meant for informational purposes only.

Comment: This image is only displayed. But I cant able to select first option

Comment: Can you add an image of the screen that you get?